# Insert white space before the last three characters

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a table of UK postcodes. All of them are in different format, some are capitalized with white space some are not. What I want to do is format them so they can follow the UK postcode standard. For instance `AB1 2BB`.

I used this query for the purpose which does work, but some postcodes have a longer or shorter first part so it does not succeed for all.

```
SELECT UPPER(INSERT((REPLACE(postcode , ' ', '')) , 4, 0, ' ')) AS postcode
```

However if I try to do it the other way around

```
SELECT UPPER(INSERT((REPLACE(postcode , ' ', '')) , -4, 0, ' ')) AS postcode
```

It does not work and returns all the postcodes glued together e.g `AB12BB`

What I want is to put a space before the last 3 characters.

Comment: Please provide sample data, desired results, an explanation of "UK postcode standard", and what "longer or shorter first part" means.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you want:

```
select concat_ws(' ',
                 left(replace(postcode, ' ', ''), 3),
                 right(replace(postcode, ' ', ''), 3
                ) as standardized_postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're going to be dealing with postcodes like this:

LS10 1DH

LS101DH

LS63DR

etc. We should start by removing all of the spaces:

```
REPLACE(postcode,' ','') -- LS10 1DH becomes LS101DH
```

taking the last 3 characters:

```
RIGHT(REPLACE(postcode,' ',''), 3) -- 1DH
```

and all of the characters up to the 3rd from last:

```
LEFT(REPLACE(postcode,' ',''), LEN(REPLACE(postcode,' ','')) - 3))
```

Then use CONCAT to bring it all together:

```
SET @postcode = 'LS101DH';

SELECT CONCAT(LEFT(REPLACE(@postcode,' ',''), LENGTH(REPLACE(@postcode,' ','')) - 3),
    ' ', -- add a space in
    RIGHT(REPLACE(@postcode,' ',''), 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

Insert a space at the 3th char from the end of the string, after you remove all the spaces:

```
SELECT UPPER(INSERT(REPLACE(postcode , ' ', ''), LENGTH(REPLACE(postcode , ' ', '')) - 2, 0, ' ')) AS postcode
```

Answer (score 0):

```
for pc in postcodes:
    print('{} {}'.format(pc[:-3], pc[-3:]))
```

Seems to work for a given list of UK postcodes for me.